# CGI program gives 405 error on shared hosting

Tags: cgi, shared-hosting

I have moved the website a few weeks back, its was working fine the previous hosting now its gives 405 error.

I have perl installed on linux server.

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi (with 58 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail).

Can someone guide what other configurations are missing?

I am sending post request to .file and then its process the data from form.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require "cgi-lib.pl";
```

Comment: This is a web server config issue.

Comment: It's impossible to give any help without a lot more information. I'd start by looking in the web server error log.

Comment: This question should not have been moved to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guess, are you trying to send a POST request? If the location of the CGI script is not configured to run CGI scripts, the server likely thinks you are trying to access a static resource. As such, you can't POST to that, and you get the 405 (Method not allowed) error.

Comment: How it can be changed?

Comment: You need to configure the web server to handle CGI scripts. Your shared hosting should have documention on that. You didn't mention which server you are using, but you can look in the docs for that server as well.

Comment: Its plex ngnix  by https://linux.isoc.net, Pleaseprovide suggestions